# What are best practices for a bookmarklet?

Tags: urls, sharing, bookmarklet

I'm creating a social sharing bookmarklet and button that lets users share a link along with an optional text.

What structure is more recommended to use?

this:

> http://www.example.com/?share=http://www.example.net&text=hello

or with a folder:

> http://www.example.com/share/?url=http://www.example.net&text=hello

(Or a completely different one?)

Comment: Do you see a particular user experience benefit one way or the other?

Comment: What is the UX aspect of this question ?

Comment: Usually the way to find out what best practices are is to visit a lot of sites that do what you're looking for. Evaluate what's best for your situation and what's not. (Remember that best practices change over time. What was best in 2013 might be pretty lousy now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think that using share as a variable in the URL describes the nature of the link more readily instead of a "folder" called share.

```
http://www.example.com/?share=http://www.example.net&text=hello
```

It explicitly implies that the URL following "share=" is the URL being shared as opposed to:

```
http://www.example.com/share/?url=http://www.example.net&text=hello
```

which doesn't imply the intended action as well. I also like Kayo's version, it makes for a more descriptive URL while defeating the arbitrary nature of having share as a "folder".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the '/share/' sub-directory would be needed. Perhaps be more explicit in your variable names.

```
http://www.example.com/?shareURL=http://www.example.net&shareText=hello
```